# Log Post Value in ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

I have setPostValue in ASIFormDataRequest. like so:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setPostValue:@"helmi" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"123" forKey:@"password"];
[request setPostValue:@"goods" forKey:@"purchase"];

NSLog(@"...");
```

I'd like to show the NSLog of Post Value before send to server. reasons is because I have many variable value in post value, need to check whether I put correctly.

Comment: try `NSLog(@"%@",[request valueForKey@"postData"])`

Comment: Wow. thank you. it works :). you shall answer so i could accept it.

Comment: I hadn't tried so I wasn't sure that it works. Anyways posted the ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ASIFormDataRequest` holds a variable called postData which is an `NSMutableArray`. You can access its value using

```
NSLog(@"%@", [request valueForKey@"postData"])
```